# Stack around Variable a is corrupted

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[10] = { 10,2,9,4,5,6,7,8,3,1 };
    /*Implementing Bubble Sort */
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the program I'm getting values sorted but one value has some garbage value and the dialogue box appears that stack around variable is corrupted in VS 2019.  In some other compiler I'm getting 0 in place of 10 in compiler.

Comment: Step 1: Drop this into your debugger and step through it line by line to be sure it's working correctly.

Comment: Yeah i did it , actually i was trying to get the value of a[10] in the inner for loop , which was not defined so the error was coming

Comment: We all make little mistakes like this, so good you could find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner for .loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
{
    if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
    {
        temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j + 1];
        array[j + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because when `j` is equal to `9` for the first iteration of the outer loop that is when `i` is equal to `0` the index in the expression `array[j + 1]` can be equal to `10` that results in accessing the memory beyond the array.

Rewrite the loop like

```
for (int j = 1; j < 10 - i; j++)
{
    if (array[j-1] > array[j])
    {
        temp = array[j-1];
        array[j-1] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you this logic slightly edited from yours.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[10] = { 10,2,9,4,5,6,7,8,3,1 };
    /*Implementing Bubble Sort */
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```